# Is Identity Increment taken into consideration when replicating a table where condition?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a SQL Server merge replication between the main node (which is the publisher that has table a) and multiple scattering nodes (which are the subscribers that replicate table a where condition which means only specific rows will be replicated when the condition is to happen) the table a has an identity primary key, so the the question is when adding new rows from the publisher or the subscriber ,is the increment happened by taking into consideration the other nodes are adding in the same times? I mean is it possible to happen a conflict for duplicating ids?

I read the below thread but I am still confusing if I have one publisher and 10 subscribers what may I do? Or do I have to cancel identity column and regenerate the id manually, specially I have already data on the publisher table

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/replicate-identity-columns?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do the subscribers have rows being inserted independently of the publisher?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid what do you mean by independently? the subscriber doesnot have the whole table of the publisher, it has only few rows where condition and , lets say a pos system , each point has a quota of the publisher table depending on its privilege

Comment: How do records get to the subscribers? Is it solely from the publisher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not handle identity across servers. You need to allocate identity ranges by yourself, e.g. server 1: 1-100000, server 2: 100001-20000 etc. You can schedule a sql job to monitor and update the ranges on each server.